# How do I load an mbox content without inserting into the dom

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics, mbox

I'm trying to interface with Adobe Test & Target because I want to load JSON rather than markup through my mbox. I want to load some mbox content into javascript and manually add it to the DOM. I have searched all over for full documentation of the mbox.js but I can't find anything other than the very basics. It describes how to use `mboxDefine()` and `mboxUpdate` to target a specific dom element. Is there a function that just returns the content?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

T&T does not offer a function to assign the response to a javascript variable.  Basically the way it works is `mbox.js` builds a url to their server and then then outputs a script include tag. This is done to get around the same origin policy limitations (cross-site scripting).

In order to handle whatever is in the html offer, they put it in their own javascript variable on their server and then output it as that as the response.  However, they also have the response output the code that updates the target element.  So there's nothing you can do to actually stop them from updating the target element with the html offer contents. They simply don't expose that.

**However**, you don't have to put html in an html offer. You can put json (javascript) in an html offer. Just do like

html offer 'myJsonMbox' (in interface)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var myJsonString = "[json string]";
</script>
```

Then on your page (inside your body tag, but before your code that wants to use it) you'd have the regular mbox code:

```
<div class='mboxDefault'></div>
<script type='test/javascript'>
mboxCreate('myJsonMbox');
</script>
```

And then somewhere after that, where you're wanting to do something with it, that `myJsonString` is there for you to reference. Or, you can do it with the `mboxDefine` and `mboxUpdate` sometime after page load, if you prefer.

Is there some particular reason why you don't think this will work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can:

a- Insert JS code you are going to use to manually manipulate the DOM

b- Insert CSS code you can use to alter the original HTMl or the newly added HTML.

c- Insert a call to a 3rd party script that will load content from a 3rd party server if needed, or the same server.

Comment: I realize this is years old, but the question is something I am looking to get answered now, and I fail to see how this comment has _anything_ to do with the question. Admittedly the T&T/mbox stuff is a black box to me, but this seems like: a) a completely generic answer, and b) nothing that is really helpful regarding the question. Am I crazy?

Comment: I re-read it and it is clear to me. And it has been years since I don't work with mboxes.

The questions is: how to insert content in the mbox that is not in the DOM? 

the answer to me is clear, load it after the pages loads, into the mbox.

Comment: > load it after the pages loads, into the mbox. < _HOW?_ Your answer provides nothing specific to actually solve the issue. You provide abstract concepts as an "answer", yet all the concepts provided are nothing that any developer beyond a hobbyist would not already think of. It may be useful to someone with little/no experience, but I _assume_ anyone asking this question is beyond that point. Your answer is also nearly 2 years _after_ the accepted answer yet is not even near the same quality, and provides little/no value. Just sayin...